# Can anyone explain why my php file isn't running in var/www/html?

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I have written a very simple rest API using PHP, the program works fine as a container in my local machine. I then further integrate CI testing for it, and I get this error. Any help will be appreciated.

**output from CI**
[image: output from CI]

**Same curl in my local container**
[image: Same curl in my local container]

Comment: Could you share your `gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: @Tschösi  http://gitlab.hal.davecutting.uk/40235226/web-add/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: I can't access that link. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) why you should copy paste your code/output instead of images.